# IOC in AngularJS (1.x) - How can I achieve?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, inversion-of-control

I'm looking for some way to add `IOC` to my `angularjs` application.

My app is a multi tenant app and I need to use different services for different tenants with the same registration name.

I'm using `TypeScript` as well and it works well with using concrete types over interfaces.

My main problem is how can I decide how to register the correct service to my application.

This is an example:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

// common registrations
app.service('commonService1', commonServiceFunction1);
app.service('commonService2', commonServiceFunction2);
app.service('commonService3', commonServiceFunction3);
app.service('commonService4', commonServiceFunction4);

// here I want to register the same service name with a different implementation
app.service('serviceName', serviceOneFunction); // sometimes I will need this service
app.service('serviceName', serviceTwoFunction); // sometimes I will need this service
```

Things I thought about:

1. Add some logic and download the correct js files per source - Function names will stay the same and I will need to figure out a way to provide the correct js file that includes the correct functions.
2. Override the registrations (e.g. register the common service and then override the registration with a specific implementation).

Both solutions ugly and not scalable to me.

I would like to have a IOC container or some other solution that is a bit more nice and scalable.

Comment: What kind of criteria do use to determine which service you need? Should services be defined per application or you need to change them dynamically?

Comment: Services will need to be changed in a configuration. Since I want to register the correct service on my application, I will not change this registration during the use of my application.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood question correct, you can register services(which are actually providers) as provider which you configure at angular configuration step. 
So, it may look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

// common registrations
app.service('commonService1', commonServiceFunction1);
app.service('commonService2', commonServiceFunction2);
app.service('commonService3', commonServiceFunction3);
app.service('commonService4', commonServiceFunction4);

app.provider('serviceName', function ServiceNameProvider() {
    var service = DefaultService;

    this.setService = function(newService) {
        service = newService
    }

    this.$get = [function() {
        return service;
    }];
});

app.config(["serviceNameProvider", function(serviceNameProvider) {  
    if(someCondition) {
        serviceNameProvider.setService(ServiceImpl1);
    } else {
        serviceNameProvider.setService(ServiceImpl2);
    } 
}]);
```

Services, factory are just syntactic sugar over provider. You can determine your service function at configuration stage of angular. `ServiceImpl1`, `ServiceImpl2` are just functions but you can use dependency injection there as they will be called by provider `with $injector.invoke`. [Read about providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

Comment: I thought about using a provider but that's not scalable and this will need a special treatment for each tenant x service. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Anyway you have to have some kind of special treatment for each tenant it can be configuration for IoC or provider. Can't you delegate that part to build process and load different modules with services depends on build flag?

Comment: I was thinking of somehow loading a json configuration that will actually configure a ioc container somehow and hook on angular's resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. Try Using angular factory.

```
angular.module('app').factory('tenantService', function() {
  var tenantService = undefined;

  if(tenantType == "1"){
     tenantService = new TenantService1();
  } else if(tenantType == "2"){
     tenantService = new TenantService2();
  } else {
     tenantService = new TenantDefService();
  }
  return tenantService;
});
```

Comment: That's the most simple way to achieve what I want - but that's not scalable and this will need a special treatment for each tenant x service. Thanks anyway.